# Need some explanations about the code coverage results

Tags: code-coverage, jacoco

I'm writing to you for information or clarification on the results given by Jacoco. I'm a new Jacoco user and I'm lost.

I've been experimenting with Jacoco and have been able to report Branch coverage, Instruction coverage, Method coverage and Line coverage.
However, I didn't understand why Branch coverage is low, whereas Line coverage, Instruction coverage and even Method coverage are often close to 100%.

As an example, I'm sending you this image showing a summary table of the results.

I used Evosuite to generate the test cases.
[The different results][1]

BRcov: Branch Coverage
IScov: Instruction coverage
MTcov: Method coverage
LIcov: Line coverage

Best regards,
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/THJ2o.png

Comment: Please take the [tour], see what's on topic [help/on-topic] and provide a [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following `Example.java`

```
class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length == 0)
            new Example();
    }
}
```

execution of

```
javac Example.java
java -javaagent:jacoco-0.8.10/lib/jacocoagent.jar -cp . Example
java -jar jacoco-0.8.10/lib/jacococli.jar report jacoco.exec --classfiles Example.class --sourcefiles . --html report
```

will produce the following expected report

[image]

[image]

Every instruction of every line of every method of every class has been executed, hence 100% instruction, line, method and class coverage.
However out of two branches of if-statement only one has been executed, hence 50% branch coverage.

Comment: It's more clear for me now!  Thanks for your explanations!